# Does each code point have a corresponding name?

Tags: unicode

Many code points have names, like `a`'s name is `'LATIN SMALL LETTER A'`.

Do all code points have names?

Comment: If you could find a library function in your language that returns that name, you could test this programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not *every* code point has a name. From the Unicode standard core specification, version 12, `4.8 Name`, under `Unicode Name Property`:

> ***NR4: For all other Unicode code points of all other types (`Control`, `Private-Use`, `Surrogate`, `Noncharacter` and `Reserved`), the value of the `Name` property is the null string.***

`NR1` through `NR3` discuss the other options, specifically:

- derivation of names for Hangul symbols;
- derivation of names for non-Hangul ideographs;
- specific names for other graphic, and all format, characters.